# Strings in Python not equal due to German Umlaut

Tags: python, string, unicode-normalization

I tried to compare to strings, both contained the German Umlaut "ü". Both look literaly the same, there is also no trailing `\n` or somethins similar.

[image]

One of those bits is read from an xml-File, another from the filesystem. Comparing them letter by letter, shows a difference with the Umlaut.

[image]

The distorted Umlaut (consisting of two letters, a normal u and two upper dots) is coming from the file system. I'm using macOS High Sierra and running Python 3.7. The filename is read using os.listdir().

I'd appreciate suggestions to handle this strange behavior (getting rid of the "ü" is not an option).

Comment: Please post sample strings as text, not image

Comment: This seems to be an encoding issue; XML surely uses Unicode, so you have to ensure the file is in the same encoding.

Comment: @hurlenko I assumed that posting would have destroyed any encoding issue, therefore I did not bother to try :/. Sure it makes reproducing the issue complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of comparing the strings directly, compare their `unicodedata.normalize` results, given the same `form` parameter

From the documentation: [Comparing strings](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#comparing-strings)

> A second tool is the unicodedata module’s normalize() function that
>   converts strings to one of several normal forms, where letters
>   followed by a combining character are replaced with single characters.
>   normalize() can be used to perform string comparisons that won’t
>   falsely report inequality if two strings use combining characters
>   differently

```py
import unicodedata

def compare_strs(s1, s2):
    def NFD(s):
        return unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)

    return NFD(s1) == NFD(s2)
```